# Get phone number OR Null (which has the max edited date) for each customer

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, max

I have 2 tables : `customer` and `phone`.

The table `phone` may contain several phone numbers by `customer` or not.

I tried to get the phone which has the max edit date.

```
SELECT customer.customer_name, phone.phone_number
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.customer_id = customer.customer_id
AND phone.edit_date  =
  (SELECT MAX(edit_date)
  FROM phone ph
  WHERE ph.customer_id = customer.customer_id
  GROUP BY ph.customer_id
  )
```

I got the error

> ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a sub query.

If there is 10 customers and 40 phones, I have to get 10 rows is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, p.phone_number
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY edit_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM phone p
     ) p
     ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id and p.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
with phone_max_edit as  
  (SELECT customer_id, phone_number
     FROM phone ph
    WHERE ph.edit_date  =
      (SELECT MAX(ph2.edit_date)
         FROM phone ph2
        WHERE ph2.customer_id = ph.customer_id
  )
SELECT customer.customer_name, phone_max_edit.phone_number
FROM customer
     LEFT JOIN phone_max_edit 
          ON phone_max_edit.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate the data in the `PHONE` table first; use the `LAST` aggregate function (a very useful function that a lot of practitioners ignore - even advanced ones, as demonstrated by answers posted in this and other threads).  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm#SQLRF00653

Then add the `LEFT JOIN` as you have in your code already.

```
SELECT customer.customer_name, ph.phone_number
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN 
( select   customer_id, 
           max(phone_number) keep (dense_rank last order by edit_date) as phone_number
  from     phone
  group by customer_id
) ph
ON ph.customer_id = customer.customer_id
;
```